# question concerning NSLog output %i, %d

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I have question concerning a function I created. 
I would like to show the timeinterval in my console output.

```
-(void)MyTimeInterval:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *then = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:then];

    NSLog(@"let me see the timeinterval between now and then %d", interval);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I should use to see the interval in the console output. 
It's not %d... I don't think I'm doing something wrong here in my function ( could be wrong of course ) , so I'm guessing it must be %d.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you are looking for is %f.  This is specifier to display a floating point number. NSTimeInterval is a floating point number with the unit being seconds

Comment: I have a related question, if i went tried to nslog %f interval/3600.0f, the nslog would say NAN?  It doesn't makes sense.